# Convert multiple string values (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, android-sqlite, data-conversion

Good Morning All!

This is my first time posting on this site after scouring for advice since I tried my hand at Python.

I'm working on pulling data from a sqlite database and inputting it into an Excel spreadsheet. I've learned how to pull the data, and get it written to a spreadsheet. The issue I'm having though, is one of the values in a table I'm pulling data from presents a dollar amount as a string. For example, $1000.00 is represented by 100000. At first glance it would appear to be $100000, but the application, for whatever reason, stores $1000.00 as 100000.

So my question: Is there a way I can convert these string values into a float, OR into another string to input the dollar sign, and decimal point to show the proper figure? This isn't a conversion for just one value either. It needs to be a blanket conversion, so that whenever I run the script it converts the data no matter what dollar amounts are presented.

So if the table contains values of 50000, 20000, 30000, 5000, 500, I need to be able to convert them into $500.00, $200.00, $300.00, $50.00, $5.00.

I hope that all makes sense and I appreciate any help anyone can give me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must divide the value by `100` to strip of the last 2 `0`s and then use the function [`printf()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#printf) to format:

```
printf("$%.2f", columnname / 100)
```

Replace `columnname` with the name of your column.

So the result of:

```
select printf("$%.2f", 500 / 100)
```

is:

```
$5.00
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ozkGqbnhnc3DMCUWajjV88/0).

Comment: This is great, thank you. And thanks for the demo as well! That showed exactly how I needed this done. Also, does the "%" sign represent a wild card value for whatever value is in the cell for that particular column?

Comment: So one problem I'm having is when there is "cents" involved. So let's say there's a value of 8888, which should be $88.88

I used the statement you provided, and it prints 8888 as $88.00. Any thoughts why it doesn't pick up the 88 cents value?

Comment: In your question you don't mention any cents.Instead of 100 use `100.0`:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ozkGqbnhnc3DMCUWajjV88/1

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to convert the values in Python you could do something like this:

```py
new_value = float(old_value) / 100
```

That will attempt to cast the string as a float value and then divide it by 100 to correct the decimal place. If precision is important you may want to use the decimal type instead of float though.